# How is this called in a snowflake schema?

Tags: schema

I'm learning the basics of DWH modeling and I didn't find a name to refer to what I colored in red in the image below, i.e. a group of tables related to each other, with one of them being related to the fact table?

[image]

**Does this have a name? (e.g. relationship branch?)**

Comment: One of the difference between a star schema and a snowflake schema is that in the latter, dimension tables are normalised in several tables. I dont know if that has a special name though

Answer (score 1):

In Kimball terminology it would be a [ﬁxed depth hierarchy](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/fixed-depth-hierarchy/). Using Inmon I think just a normalised dimension.

Comment: It's a fixed depth hierarchy implemented as a Snowflake dimension.  Kimball would typically put all the columns onto the Shop table, making it a Star, rather than a Snowflake.